Ubuntu 24.04 How to setup autoinstall with custom scripts
i have one question i was trying to achieve autoinstall setup of ubuntu 24.04, and it was successful. But main problem was I created option for user to interactive setup timezone, keyboard, username and hostname. Since I want semi-auto installation. In process I use script to enroll device into Landscape. But since script is executed in process before hostname and username is determinated, device will enroll with default hostname and username, it will enroll as Ubuntu  instead of for example PC-DEVICE-L? How I can  create autoinstall which will run script after I setup hostname ?
Or is there any option to create iso with autoenroll option to landscape?

My suggestion is to run your custom script during the first boot of the device after installation.  The hostname will be correct at that point.
You can use the user-data section to add configuration that cloud-init will use during the first boot.
This example simply logs the hostname when the command is run.  The commands can be customized to your needs.
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  user-data:
    runcmd:
    - hostname > /run/hostname.log


TLDR: May be the easiest way is to use server distribution with Subiquity, instead of desktop distribution with Ubuntu Desktop Installer wrapper around Subiquity and Cloud Init, with subsequent desktop install from packages.
The rationale:
The problem is lost of interactivity during install in desktop variant installation since year 2023, if you have to customize a thing. I.e. in case of enabling of autoinstall section (it's configuration of Subiquity under the hood, with it's capabilities) there is absence of capability to enter a thing by an end-user before, during or directly after the process of copy of files into target OS instance file system by installer. The feature's side effect is removal of interactivity at all if you are using it "as is" for your customs. Semi-auto installation was removed during 2023.
The other problem is that Snap unable to work without Systemd init daemon strictly with PID 1, without huge amount of complex things. Leading to a lot of complexities and moving OS install parts into first boot. I.e. no more usual Linux way of customizing in chroot. And there are no installer's hooks to do the job in time (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478772).
There is capability of interaction with an end-user during OS boot (to request login, set password, hostname). But it's broken by Cloud Init (CI) logging into TTY. The logs are leading to Systemd's interactivity is stalled. Thus, you have to refactor configurations of OS installers parts. In order to work strictly before CI, or strictly after, during a boot. In order to request an input in time. That's a quest with tricky Systemd units ordering orchestration. In fact the orchestration not obvious due to properties of the things to be launched.
If you need exclusive access to end-users home directory before the end of configuration management, you are facing with Gnome is locking files in the directory (may be snapped apps - too). I.e. your sudoer may start to act manually earlier, or a software starting to lock a files earlier, than configuration management is over.
In general, autoinstall section is landed by the set of installers into /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg in OS instance to be installed, into field datasource.None.userdata_raw and applied during first boot of the OS. This is giving an idea of further hacks. The example by Andrew Lowther will not work until you add autoinstall.version=1 into the Yaml.
If you are a corporate engineer:
If the OS instance is going to be attached to configuration management (CM) like you do, then it's expected CM fully knows how to pick up the instance and there is nothing to be entered by end-user (no need to request a user to enter proper hostname without a typos - no need to put onto an end-user the task of writing a configuration). Then, pick up process in CM can be split into several independent parts:

Common parts, to be applied before knowledge of account data. Leading to put of the host into preliminary environment.
An independent parts to be started upon an account name became known.
Host's name change according to results of device authentication, putting the device into primary environment. May involve end-users account knowledge too.

Also you have smth. like IPA server or AD with LDAP, along with integration with CM database of assets. Which allows to overcome the issues with late login/password knowledge and acknowledge a device automatically, without bothering of an end-user by manual administration tasks.
In fact there are independent parts in the context of the question. That's why you asked not one question. There are:

OS install,
device recognition (authentication) by CM,
OS provisioning by CM,
end-user environment provisioning by CM.

Only first one in the list is the task for OS installer
P.S. You are writing: "In process I use script to enroll device into Landscape. But since script is executed in process before hostname and username is determinated...".
How do you achieved it? The data is requested earlier, than the /target chroot is created. Or you are working during first boot and your friend is Systemd ordering of units start. But, you have to insert the files before the boot, when the hooks are absent in case of manual user input.
